# MediaProjection for screen capture - How to change resolution?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, screen-capture, mediaprojection

Take this block of example code:

```
// from window manager
val recordWidth = screenWidth
val recordHeight = screenHeight

val projection: MediaProjection = // retrieved from API

val mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
    setVideoSource(SURFACE)
    setOutputFormat(MPEG_4)
    setVideoFrameRate(frameRate) // e.g. 30
    setVideoEncoder(H264)
    setVideoSize(recordWidth, recordHeight)
    setVideoEncodingBitRate(videoBitRate)
    setOutputFile(outputFile)
    prepare()
}

val virtualDisplay: VirtualDisplay = projection?.createVirtualDisplay(
        "Example",
        screenWidth,
        screenHeight,
        screenDensity,
        VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
        mediaRecorder.surface,
        null,
        null
)

mediaRecorder.start()
```

This all works well, as long as **screenWidth** and **screenHeight** match that of the display.

If I change **recordWidth** and **recordHeight** (which are passed to the `MediaRecorder` with `setVideoSize(Int, Int)`), then all goes wrong. *The recorded video tends to contain just the upper left section of the overall screen.*

So my main questions:

1. Does something special have to be done to reduce resolution when
   recording the screen? Even if I keep the aspect ratio with the
   screen, it doesn't seem to work.
2. Some width/height values cause a
   crash - is there an API to retrieve supported screen recording
   sizes? I know `Camera` provides one, but this isn't really using the
   Camera APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer this one
     this.mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);

```
    Log.d(TAG, "startRecording...");

    this.mVideoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(format, width, height);

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FPS);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 0);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
```

Comment: how this will help?